# Cannot install yum on CentOS 5.3, 64bits

Tags: centos5, yum

I'm facing a problem with installing yum in CentOS (version 5.3, 64bits). My CentOS yum is not preinstalled, so I can't install other package that I need. I found out one article that show how to install yum on CentOS (both 32bits and 64bits), but it doesn't work for me.

**Command to install yum**

```
rpm import http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5.3/os/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
rpm -ihv http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.3/os/x86_64/CentOS/libxml2-2.6.26-2.1.2.7.i386.rpm
rpm -ihv http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.3/os/x86_64/CentOS/libxml2-python-2.6.26-2.1.2.7.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ihv http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5.3/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-elementtree-1.2.6-5.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ihv http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5.3/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-iniparse-0.2.3-4.el5.noarch.rpm
rpm -ihv http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5.3/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-sqlite-1.1.7-1.2.1.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ihv http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5.2/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-urlgrabber-3.1.0-2.noarch.rpm
rpm -ihv http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5.2/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-urlgrabber-3.1.0-2.noarch.rpm
rpm -ihv http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5.2/os/x86_64/CentOS/sqlite-3.3.6-2.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ihv http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5.2/os/x86_64/CentOS/yum-metadata-parser-1.1.2-2.el5.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ihv http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5.2/os/x86_64/CentOS/yum-3.2.8-9.el5.centos.1.noarch.rpm
```

When I type the command and enter, error is thrown:

```
/bin/rpm: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter
```

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thank in advance!

Comment: How on earth did you break this system? You would probably do better to reinstall it.

Comment: You would be better off explaining how you got into this situation in the first place.

Comment: you are trying to execute a 32bit executable on a 64bit system: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328250/centos-64-bit-bad-elf-interpreter